# iOS CoreText get list of registered fonts via CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont

Tags: ios, fonts, core-text, uifont

I am registering fonts dynamically via the following:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation{

    if ([url isFileURL])
    {
        // Handle file being passed in
        NSLog(@"handleOpenURL: %@",url.absoluteString);


        NSData *inData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        CFErrorRef error;
        CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)inData);
        CGFontRef fontRef = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(provider);

        UIFont *font;
        if (!CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(fontRef, &error)) {
            CFStringRef errorDescription = CFErrorCopyDescription(error);
            NSLog(@"Failed to load font: %@", error);
            CFRelease(errorDescription);
        } else {
            CFStringRef fontNameRef = CGFontCopyPostScriptName(fontRef);
            NSLog(@"fontNameRef: %@",fontNameRef);
            font = [UIFont fontWithName:(__bridge NSString *)fontNameRef size:80];
            [self.arrayOfFonts addObject:(__bridge NSString *)fontNameRef];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"refreshFont" object:nil];
            CFRelease(fontNameRef);
        }
        CFRelease(fontRef);
        CFRelease(provider);
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

It works fine first time. It appears that if I close the app and try to register the same font again, then it gives me the (expected) error `"Failed to load font: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreText.CTFontManagerErrorDomain Code=105 "Could not register the CGFont '<CGFont (0x1c00f5980): NeuropolXRg-Regular>'" UserInfo={NSDescription=Could not register the CGFont '<CGFont (0x1c00f5980): NeuropolXRg-Regular>', CTFailedCGFont=<CGFont (0x1c00f5980): NeuropolXRg-Regular>}"`

This seems to be because the font is already registered. The documentation for `CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont` states that it:

"Registers the specified graphics font with the font manager. Registered fonts are discoverable through font descriptor matching. Attempts to register a font that is either already registered or contains the same PostScript name of an already registered font will fail."

**How exactly to do "through font descriptor matching"??**

**How can I get a list of all fonts which have been registered via the `CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont` method so I can unregister them before registering again?**

EDIT:

I have tried using the `CTFontManagerCopyAvailablePostScriptNames` and `CTFontManagerCopyAvailableFontFamilyNames` methods but both only print out the names of the fonts already available on iOS. Not the ones I registered via `CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont`

**NOTE:** I am NOT asking about the fonts already available on iOS which can be listed by iterating over [UIFont familyNames].

Comment: Can someone help me please?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “close the app”?

Comment: Also, have you tried [`CTFontManagerCopyAvailablePostScriptNames`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/1499516-ctfontmanagercopyavailablepostsc)?

Comment: @robmayoff Yes, I have tried using the `CTFontManagerCopyAvailablePostScriptNames` and `CTFontManagerCopyAvailableFontFamilyNames` methods but both only print out the names of the fonts already available on iOS. Not the ones I registered via `CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont`.

Comment: @robmayoff by close the app I mean if I exit the app from the app switcher and then run the app again and try to register the same font again.

Comment: @robmayoff I am sorry to bother you. Did you have any other suggestions I could try?

Comment: @PranoyC why not just attempt unregistering it at first, success or fail you'll register it again

Comment: Where/how is your data actually stored when you register the font? Can you access that and get any useful information?

Comment: I was trying to find more info about my previous question and came up with the possibility apple doesnt let you directly access that data - @AntonTheDev may have the cleanest solution.

Comment: @AntonTheDev I contacted Apple DTS and I shared my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45284412/1634905

Comment: @solenoid Thank you for trying to help me! You are correct. I contacted Apple DTS and I shared my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45284412/1634905

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I logged a ticket with Apple DTS (Developer Technical Support) and they said:

"You need to keep track of the fonts you have registered using CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont yourself. The error code kCTFontManagerErrorAlreadyRegistered returned by CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont will tell you if you have already registered a font. Using font descriptor matching to discover if your fonts are installed probably isn’t a good way to go as the system may choose to perform font substitution for missing fonts. Installing a font using CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont simply makes it available for your app’s use.  It is not a query service for discovering installed fonts. If that is not sufficient for your preferences, then I think it would be a good idea for you to consider filing a feature request asking for the functionality you would like to receive."

So basically, we need to keep track of the fonts we register ourselves.

**Solution/Work-around I ended up using:**

Currently my app allows users to add fonts using the `Action Sheet's` "Copy to MYAPP" button on a font file. This same solution also works for font files which I download from my server.

In order for my app to be listed in the Action Sheet for `.ttf` and `.otf` files, in my app's info.plist, I added a new Document type:

```
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
            <array/>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>Font</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.opentype-font</string>
                <string>public.truetype-ttf-font</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

This allows my app to show in the `action sheet` on any font file. So user can put the font file on dropbox, google drive or any other file sharing app. Then they can import the font from there into my app. After importing, I need to move the font file from the temporary `tmp` `inbox` folder to my app's `Documents` `fonts` directory. The `fonts` directory keeps all the custom fonts. After that, I register this custom font and add the name to the `self.arrayOfFonts` array. This is the array which contains the list of all my fonts.

Also it appears that `CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont` is only for the session. So when the app is closed from the App Switcher and relaunched, that font is no longer registered. So after every startup, I go through my `documents/fonts` folder and re-register all the fonts and add their names to the `self.arrayOfFonts` array.

Rest of my app code to get this working:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation{

    if ([url isFileURL])
    {
        // Handle file being passed in
        NSLog(@"handleOpenURL: %@, extension: %@",url.absoluteString,url.pathExtension);
        [self moveFontFrom:url];
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
}

-(void)moveFontFrom:(NSURL*)fromurl{
    NSString *stringPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fonts"];
    // New Folder is your folder name
    NSError *error1 = nil;
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:stringPath]){
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:stringPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error1];
    }
    NSLog(@"error1: %@", error1.debugDescription);
    NSURL *tourl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",stringPath,[[fromurl absoluteString] lastPathComponent]] isDirectory:NO];

    NSLog(@"Trying to move from:\n\n%@\n\nto:\n\n%@\n\n", fromurl.absoluteString,tourl.absoluteString);

    NSError* error2;
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:tourl.path]){
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:tourl.path error:&error2];
        NSLog(@"Deleting old existing file at %@ error2: %@", tourl.path,error2.debugDescription);
    }


    NSError* error3;
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtURL:fromurl toURL:tourl error:&error3];
    NSLog(@"error3: %@", error3.debugDescription);

    if (!error3) {
        NSString *fontName = [self registerFont:tourl checkIfNotify:YES];
        if (fontName) {
            if (![self.arrayOfFonts containsObject:fontName]) {
                [self.arrayOfFonts addObject:fontName];
                [self.arrayOfFonts sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"refreshFont" object:nil userInfo:@{@"font":fontName}];
            }
        }
    }
}

-(void)startupLoadFontsInDocuments{

    self.arrayOfFonts = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSString *location = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fonts"];
    NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:location error:NULL];
    for (NSInteger count = 0; count < [directoryContent count]; count++)
    {
        NSLog(@"File %ld: %@/%@", (count + 1), location,[directoryContent objectAtIndex:count]);
        NSString *fontName = [self registerFont:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",location,[directoryContent objectAtIndex:count]] isDirectory:NO] checkIfNotify:NO];
        if (fontName) {
            if (![self.arrayOfFonts containsObject:fontName]) {
                [self.arrayOfFonts addObject:fontName];
            }
        }
    }
    [self.arrayOfFonts sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
}

-(NSString*)registerFont:(NSURL *)url checkIfNotify:(BOOL)checkIfNotify{
    NSData *inData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    CFErrorRef registererror;
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)inData);
    CGFontRef fontRef = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(provider);
    NSString *fontName = (__bridge NSString *)CGFontCopyPostScriptName(fontRef);
    BOOL registerFontStatus = CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(fontRef, &registererror);
    if (!registerFontStatus) {
        CFStringRef errorDescription = CFErrorCopyDescription(registererror);
        NSError *registererr = (__bridge NSError*)registererror;
        if ([registererr code]==kCTFontManagerErrorAlreadyRegistered) {
            NSLog(@"Font is already registered!");
        }
        NSLog(@"Failed to load font: %@", registererror);
        CFRelease(errorDescription);

        /*CFErrorRef unregistererror;
    BOOL unregisterFont = CTFontManagerUnregisterGraphicsFont(fontRef, &unregistererror);
    NSLog(@"Font unregister status: %d",unregisterFont);
    CFStringRef unregistererrorDescription = CFErrorCopyDescription(unregistererror);
    NSError *unregistererr = (__bridge NSError*)unregistererror;
    NSInteger code = [unregistererr code];

    NSLog(@"Failed to unregister font: %@", unregistererr);
    CFRelease(unregistererrorDescription);*/

        if (checkIfNotify) {
            UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Already added" message:@"That font is already added to the app. Please select it from the fonts list." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
            [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

            }]];
            [[self.window rootViewController] presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    } else {
        CFStringRef fontNameRef = CGFontCopyPostScriptName(fontRef);
        fontName = (__bridge NSString*)fontNameRef;
        CFRelease(fontNameRef);

        NSLog(@"fontName: %@",fontName);
    }
    CFRelease(fontRef);
    CFRelease(provider);
    return fontName;
}
```

**NOTE:** As you will noticed, I have commented out the `CTFontManagerUnregisterGraphicsFont`. The `CTFontManagerUnregisterGraphicsFont` used to unregister fonts doesn't seem to work for me as it gives an error saying the Font is in use and hence can't be un-registered. So when I need to remove a font, I simply remove it from the `self.arrayOfFonts` array and my `documents/fonts` folder.

Comment: Since iOS 13, you can use `CTFontManagerCopyRegisteredFontDescriptors` to query for fonts that are installed inside the application. Personally I'm still missing a method for querying fonts that are installed by the user outside the app, using third-party font installer apps.

Answer (score 1):

What you should be using is something like this:

```
- (void)getInstalledFonts {
    NSDictionary *descriptorOptions = @{(id)kCTFontDownloadableAttribute : @YES};
    CTFontDescriptorRef descriptor = CTFontDescriptorCreateWithAttributes((CFDictionaryRef)descriptorOptions);
    CFArrayRef fontDescriptors = CTFontDescriptorCreateMatchingFontDescriptors(descriptor, NULL);
    [self showExistingFonts:(NSArray *)CFBridgingRelease(fontDescriptors)];
    CFRelease(descriptor);
}

- (void)showExistingFonts:(NSArray *)fontList {
    NSMutableDictionary *fontFamilies = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    for(UIFontDescriptor *descriptor in fontList) {
        NSString *fontFamilyName = [descriptor objectForKey:UIFontDescriptorFamilyAttribute];
        NSMutableArray *fontDescriptors = [fontFamilies objectForKey:fontFamilyName];
        if(!fontDescriptors) {
            fontDescriptors = [NSMutableArray new];
            [fontFamilies setObject:fontDescriptors forKey:fontFamilyName];
        }

        [fontDescriptors addObject:descriptor];
    }

}
```

Taken from:
https://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/ios7-day-by-day-day-22-downloadable-fonts

Comment: I tried this and did `NSLog` of the `fontFamilyName`. I tested with 3 custom fonts but none of them were listed. It printed out all the names which I could also get via `[UIFont familyNames]` but it didn't print my custom font which I registered via `CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont`.

Comment: Try using other descriptorOptions. There are many available https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/core_text_constants

Comment: I tried `kCTFontDownloadedAttribute`, `kCTFontDownloadableAttribute` and no luck from them either. I contacted Apple DTS and they said that I need to keep track of my fonts myself and "Using font descriptor matching to discover if your fonts are installed probably isn’t a good way to go as the system may choose to perform font substitution for missing fonts."

I ended up using a work-around solution which I shared here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45284412/1634905

Comment: That's weird because their documentation as you've quoted does state differently

Comment: yep. I agree with you. But at this point I am going ahead with the workaround solution as I have spent a lot of time on this issue already. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

**I found that if you ever use UIFont(name:) with the font that you loaded dynamically. that the CTFontManagerUnregisterFontsForURL doesn't work as stated above.**

**So the workaround is to use**

```
let desc = UIFontDescriptor(name: <name>, size: <size>)

let font = UIFont(descriptor: desc, size: <size>)
```

**If at any time you use UIFont(name: ) the unregister doesn't really unregister it.**

**Not I found this to be the case with CTFontManager Register/Unregstier FontsForURL api and GraphicsFont apis.**