# List of installed fonts

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I am working on an application where the user can install different custom fonts. The application presents the user a table list of fonts he can install. (3 random fonts provided for this example)

[image]

The fonts are downloaded when the user opens the app, and the fonts are dynamically loaded with this function. The custom fonts are not added in the info.plist.

```
func install_font(font_path : String) -> Bool
{
    let font_data = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: font_path))

    if let provider = CGDataProvider.init(data: font_data as CFData)
    {
        var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?

        let font:CGFont = CGFont(provider)!

        if (!CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, &error))
        {
            print(error.debugDescription)
            return false
        }
        else
        {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

Until now I was using this function, but this displays all fonts: installed ones and the dynamically loaded.

```
func show_all_fonts()
{
    UIFont.familyNames.forEach({ familyName in
        let fontNames = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: familyName)
        print(familyName, fontNames)
    })
}
```

Is there any way to display only the installed fonts? I need a method to differentiate the installed fonts vs the fonts dynamically loaded, so I can put a checkmark on table cell for the installed ones.

Comment: maybe this question will be helpful for you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44613397/ios-coretext-get-list-of-registered-fonts-via-ctfontmanagerregistergraphicsfont

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, if you want to differentiate your fonts from the native fonts, why don't your simply compare the results show_all_fonts() with show_only_my_custom_fonts(), which you already have a list of?

Comment: Because after I load into memory the custom fonts, they are also displayed on show_all_fonts(), even if I don’t have them installed.

Comment: @mbabaev your link was very usefull in pointing me in the right direction, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you fetch and *persist* the list of installed fonts on initial launch of your app after installation. That way you can basically just run a union on the persisted font list with the after-first-launch list of fonts.

Comment: Yes, I can make a list like that. But if the user minimise the app, installs the font through a profile and then resumes the app, I don't know which font he installed. Every time user resumes the application or opens the application I need to run a search and identify algorithm to differentiate from downloaded fonts and installed fonts.

Comment: I think the best solution would be to user your algorithm, and every time user resumes the app from background, to release all loaded custom fonts, search and identify, then load them back. But question is, how do I release a dinamically loaded custom font?

Comment: Just found that CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont has a step-brother called CTFontManagerUnregisterGraphicsFont which may solve my problem.