# Registered font not getting after reopen application

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uifont, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I am using Font from `UIDocumentPickerViewController` and I am successfully registered font and also get `UIFont.families`. But once I kill the application and then reopen application then I can not get that font in `UIFont.families`. I used bellow code

```
func handleFileSelection(inUrl:URL) -> Void {
do {
    // inUrl is the document's URL
    let fontData = try Data(contentsOf: inUrl) // Getting file data here
    let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: fontData as CFData)
    let cgFont = CGFont(dataProvider
   
    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
    if !CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(cgFont!, &error)
    {
        print("Error loading Font!")
    } else {}
        let fontName = cgFont!.postScriptName
        self.lblText.font = UIFont.init(name: "\(fontName!)", size: 25.0)
        self.lblText.text = "\(fontName!)"
    } catch {
        print("document loading error")
    }
}
```

If I am missing something please let me know.

Comment: You need to save a reference to the font file -- in `UserDefaults` or your own file storage -- and then reload it when the app is relaunched.

Comment: Can you please give an example? It will help me to better understand. Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, `CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont` makes that font available **only** for the current session (that is, until the app is killed). You may want to *copy* the font file into your app's documents folder, so you can re-load it on launch - see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45284412/6257435

Comment: You might also look at [CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/1499468-ctfontmanagerregisterfontsforurl) ... I haven't used it, but the docs state under `. persistent` for the `scope` parameter *The font is available to all processes for the current user session and will be available in subsequent sessions unless unregistered.*